# Iterate conditionally and output dataframes and charts

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, seaborn

I am trying to output a dataframe and a chart for each of my 'vals'. I'm struggling to piece together some of these Pythonic basics.

Flow: I take the dataframe, do a groupby, get the percentage of total... Output a table and a chart. However, I want to loop through this process, the first time with a dataframe filter on `Reviewed?=='Yes'`, and then by `No`.

```
data = {'Region': ["US", "US", "US","US"],
        'Gender': ["M","F","F","M"],
        'Reviewed?': ["Yes","Yes","No","No"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Region','Gender','Reviewed?'])

def func(df):
    vals = ['Yes','No']
    for i in range(len(vals)):
        for x in vals:
            gb[i] = df[df['Reviewed?']==x].groupby(['Gender'])['Region'].count().reset_index()
            total[i] = gb[i]['Region'].sum()
            gb[i]['Percentage'] = (gb[i]['Region'] / total[i])
            gb[i] = gb[i].sort_values(by='Percentage', ascending=False)
            sns.barplot(data=gb[i], x='Region', y='Percentage')
    plt.show()
    return gb[i]
```

few errors messages:

`ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (0,2) into shape (0)`

`ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 2 to array axis with dimension 0`

`ValueError: Cannot set a frame with no defined index and a value that cannot be converted to a Series`

**Update**
Here is a brute force version of what I want. I just want a more efficient and dynamic way to do this.

Note, I wasn't originally explicit that I wanted to keep the counts in the final dataframe...

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

data = {'Region': ["US", "US", "US","US"],
        'Gender': ["M","F","F","M"],
        'Reviewed?': ["Yes","Yes","No","No"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Region','Gender','Reviewed?'])

def func(df):
    gb = df[df['Reviewed?']=='No'].groupby(['Gender'])['Region'].count().reset_index()
    total = gb['Region'].sum()
    gb['Percentage'] = (gb['Region'] / total)
    notyetreviewed = gb.sort_values(by='Percentage', ascending=False)
    sns.barplot(data=notyetreviewed, x='Gender', y='Percentage')
    bottom, top = plt.ylim(0,1) 
    plt.show()

    gb = df[df['Reviewed?']=='Yes'].groupby(['Gender'])['Region'].count().reset_index()
    total = gb['Region'].sum()
    gb['Percentage'] = (gb['Region'] / total)
    reviewed = gb.sort_values(by='Percentage', ascending=False)
    bottom, top = plt.ylim(0,1)  
    sns.barplot(data=reviewed, x='Gender', y='Percentage')
    plt.show()

    return notyetreviewed, reviewed
func(df)
```

Comment: You cannot get 3 `ValueErrors` in a single code run. Which is it? I appreciate that you're trying to illustrate various attempts

Comment: So, we should have 2 charts here, each showing a 50/50 split of M/F?

Comment: ha, obviously you're not as bad as me at this :) After the first value error, I get: "During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:" same thing happens after the second value error.

Comment: Yeah, I was just throwing in some dummy data for reproducible code.

Comment: I attempted to fix your indentation as it was indented very far over in `func` please review and make sure it's still correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a marginal improvement. It would be nice to see a more Pythonic solution that wouldn't require me to hard code `'Reviewed?'` into the function call...

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

data = {'Region': ["US", "US", "US","US"],
        'Gender': ["M","F","F","M"],
        'Reviewed?': ["Yes","Yes","No","No"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Region','Gender','Reviewed?'])

def func(df,group,reviewed):
    df = df[df['Reviewed?'].isin(reviewed)].groupby([group])['Region'].count().reset_index()
    df['Percentage'] = df['Region'] / df['Region'].sum()
    sns.barplot(data=df, x='Gender', y='Percentage')
    bottom, top = plt.ylim(0,1)
    plt.show()
    return df

df1 = func(df,'Gender',['Yes'])
df1 = func(df,'Gender',['No'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Region': ["US", "US", "US","US"],
        'Gender': ["M","F","F","M"],
        'Reviewed?': ["Yes","Yes","No","No"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Region','Gender','Reviewed?'])

for outcome in ['Yes', 'No']:
    filtered = df[df['Reviewed?'].eq(outcome)]['Gender'].value_counts(normalize=True)
    filtered.plot.bar()
```

In this case, I'm filtering the DF on each loop by the `Reviewed?` outcome and then getting the proportional values for male and female. Your question poses a binary choice, but I suppose it could be extended by `for outcome in df['Reviewed?'].unique():`

Comment: Almost. As mentioned, I'm trying to output the chart and the dataframes. Also, I like keeping in the counts, which is why I calced the total manually.

Comment: @Christopher I see nothing in the question about keeping the counts

Comment: Sure, I didn't ask specifically about counts, but I built it into my code as such. That's really immaterial at this point. What I did specifically ask for is outputting charts and the dataframe. Thanks for your help with this code.